# grails g:formatNumber

Tags: grails, gsp

by default tag  returns such format of specified number 1,224.37

I need to have as result following one 1 224,37

I was trying to use format field in g:formatNumber tag but without success.

Thank you for help.

Best Regards, Jakub.

Answer (score 1):

You should add groupingUsed="false" attribute for g:formatNumber tag:

```
<g:formatNumber number="1224.37" type="number" maxFractionDigits="2" format="#" groupingUsed="false"/>
```

g:formatNumber documentation:
http://grails.org/doc/1.2.x/ref/Tags/formatNumber.html